# How to change the y-axis of the censoring table in ggsurvplot in R?

Tags: r, survival-analysis, survival, survminer

The `ggsurvplot` function from the package `survminer` allows users to draw Kaplen-Meier curves. It also allows us to create a table beneath the plot with the number of censored observations by configuring the `ncensor.plot` value. My question is: how does one change the y-axis of the censored table beneath the plot? The reason is I have a study termination at for example 52 weeks, and therefore the amount of censored observations is high, skewing the table completely. See the example below.

```
#Create a random dataset with gender, event, time
set.seed(100)
time <- rnorm(n = 100, mean = 52, sd = 20)
set.seed(150)
gender <- sample(x = c(0, 1), prob = c(.6, .4), size = 100, replace = TRUE)
set.seed(100)
event <- sample(x = c(0, 1), prob = c(.4, .6), size = 100, replace = TRUE)
dat <- data.frame(time, gender, event)

#Censor time after 52 weeks
dat <- dat %>% mutate(time_adjusted = if_else(time > 52, 52, time))

#KM-estimator
survObject <- Surv(time = dat$time_adjusted, event = dat$event)
km.model <- survfit(survObject ~ gender, data = dat)
summary(km.model)

Call: survfit(formula = survObject ~ gender, data = dat)

                gender=0 
     time n.risk n.event survival   std.err lower 95% CI upper 95% CI
  6.56149     61       1 0.983607 0.0162585     0.952251     1.000000
 14.42688     58       1 0.966648 0.0231936     0.922242     1.000000
 28.42634     56       1 0.949386 0.0284876     0.895162     1.000000
 28.84541     54       1 0.931805 0.0329415     0.869427     0.998658
 28.84858     53       1 0.914224 0.0367130     0.845027     0.989087
 33.72372     52       1 0.896643 0.0399957     0.821581     0.978562
 35.49481     51       1 0.879061 0.0429020     0.798871     0.967301
 35.71242     50       1 0.861480 0.0455040     0.776755     0.955446
 37.73950     48       1 0.843533 0.0479650     0.754572     0.942981
 41.95615     45       1 0.824787 0.0504291     0.731641     0.929793
 43.23820     44       1 0.806042 0.0526518     0.709180     0.916135
 44.22292     43       1 0.787297 0.0546624     0.687131     0.902065
 48.84190     40       1 0.767615 0.0567288     0.664106     0.887257
 49.24141     39       1 0.747932 0.0585893     0.641480     0.872050
 50.42166     36       1 0.727156 0.0605334     0.617686     0.856027
 50.60166     35       1 0.706380 0.0622672     0.594300     0.839599
 51.00008     34       1 0.685605 0.0638078     0.571287     0.822798
 52.00000     33      21 0.249311 0.0619235     0.153222     0.405659

                gender=1 
    time n.risk n.event survival   std.err lower 95% CI upper 95% CI
 10.5119     39       1 0.974359 0.0253102     0.925994     1.000000
 17.2280     37       1 0.948025 0.0357936     0.880404     1.000000
 24.0235     36       1 0.921691 0.0434190     0.840402     1.000000
 28.7516     35       1 0.895357 0.0495247     0.803367     0.997880
 30.7129     33       1 0.868225 0.0549558     0.766927     0.982903
 34.1409     32       1 0.841093 0.0595606     0.732095     0.966319
 35.2230     31       1 0.813961 0.0635192     0.698519     0.948482
 35.3501     30       1 0.786829 0.0669463     0.665973     0.929616
 43.0588     26       1 0.756566 0.0708822     0.629649     0.909066
 43.2310     25       1 0.726303 0.0742265     0.594466     0.887379
 44.8028     24       1 0.696041 0.0770563     0.560275     0.864706
 46.7601     23       1 0.665778 0.0794266     0.526965     0.841157
 47.9673     21       1 0.634074 0.0817272     0.492524     0.816307
 49.9674     20       1 0.602371 0.0835642     0.458966     0.790583
 50.1777     18       1 0.568906 0.0853600     0.423959     0.763408
 52.0000     15       8 0.265489 0.0834090     0.143425     0.491439

#KM-curves
ggsurvplot(km.model, data = dat, ggtheme = theme_bw(), conf.int = TRUE, risktable = "abs_pct", ncensor.plot = TRUE,
           xlab = "Time in weeks", ylab = "Survival", xlim = c(0,52), break.x.by = 13)
```

**Output of the graph**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object returned by `ggsurvplot` is a list which contains the main plot as an element called `plot` and the censored table plot as an element named `ncensor.plot`. Both of which are `ggplot` objects and can therefore be tweaked using default ggplot options. As an example in my code below I use `scale_y_continuous` to change the `breaks` of the y scale for the censored table plot:

```r
library(survminer)
library(survival)
library(dplyr)

p <- ggsurvplot(km.model, data = dat, ggtheme = theme_bw(), conf.int = TRUE, risktable = "abs_pct", ncensor.plot = TRUE,
           xlab = "Time in weeks", ylab = "Survival", xlim = c(0,52), break.x.by = 13)

p$ncensor.plot <- p$ncensor.plot + scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(12))
#> Scale for 'y' is already present. Adding another scale for 'y', which will
#> replace the existing scale.

p
```

[image]

**EDIT** The limits of the x axis could be set using the limits argument, where I also have set the breaks according to ones set by ggsurvplot by default, except for the 52 which I replaced by 51:

```
p$ncensor.plot <- p$ncensor.plot + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(12)) + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(0, 13, 26, 39, 51), limits = c(NA, 51))

p
```

[image]

Comment: Great! Could you please share the code to limit x-axis of censor plot to 51 weeks.

Comment: Sure. See my edit.